# Put nested arrays on one line with regex

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to put the arrays of the following file on one line:

```json
{
    "name": "John",

    "age": 30,

    "cars": [

    
        {
            "name": "Ford",
            "models": [
                "Fiesta",
                "Focus",
                "Mustang"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "BMW",
            "models": [
                "320",
                "X3",
                "X5"
            ]

        },

        {


            "name": "Fiat",
            "models": [
                "500",


                "Panda"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried this regex:

```
s/:\s*\[\K\n.*?(?=\])/$&=~s@\s+@@rgs/egs
```

that allows me to put arrays on a single line, but it doesn't work for nested arrays. How can I modify it to handle nested arrays?

Comment: Regular expressions are not good at dealing with recursive structures.

Comment: Why are you doing this with a regexp instead of parsing the data as JSON and then producing the output you want from that?

Comment: In Perl there is a core library `JSON`, then there are the better `JSON::XS` and `Cpanel::JSON::XS`.   They all read a JSON string nicely, and return a Perl data structure.  Then you can pretty-print that as you like, and there are good libraries for that.  (Or parse by hand for specific requirements for how you want it to look.)  I strongly suggest not to fiddle with printing details of specific data formats, like JSON, using regex; it's going to be very messy and unreliable.  You'll mostly waste time...

Comment: Then there is the unix command-line tool `jq`

Comment: @zdim Available for Windows too, but wouldn't help here. At least not with getting the desired output.

Comment: @ikegami "_Available for Windows too..._"  -- Good to know, thanks.  And yes, it wouldn't help for what they ask, I mentioned as a general tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are good libraries in Perl for work with JSON data, shown in the question. There is a core library [JSON::PP](https://perldoc.perl.org/JSON::PP), then there are the better `JSON::XS` and [Cpanel::JSON::XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Cpanel::JSON::XS). They'll all read a JSON file/string nicely, and return a Perl data structure.

Then you can pretty-print that as you like, again using libraries. Here are two examples.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dump qw(dumpf);
use Path::Tiny;  # path()
use Cpanel::JSON::XS; 
use List::MoreUtils qw(none);  # also in List::Util in newer versions

use Data::Printer filters => [ { 
    ARRAY => sub { 
        # Print arrays on one line if at "bottom" (no further references)
        if ( none { ref } @{$_[0]} ) {
            return join ', ', map { q(").$_.q(") } @{$_[0]}
        }
        else { return }  # or return `undef` to have it passed through
    },  
}];

my $file = shift // die "Usage: $0 ilename\n"; 

my $json = path($file)->slurp; 
my $ds = Cpanel::JSON::XS->new->decode($json); 

say "w/ Data::Dump, using filters:";
say dumpf( $ds, sub {
    my ($ctx, $obj) = @_; 
    return ($ctx->is_array and none { ref } @$obj)
        ? { object => "@$obj" }
        : undef;                 # no filtering, carry on normally
});

say "\nw/ Data::Printer:";     
p( $ds, index => 0 );
```

I normally use [Data::Dump](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump) for its concise default output with `dd` and `pp`.  It prints short arrays and hashes on one line.  However, longer ones are broken up over lines for readability so here I use a filter.  The `none { ref } LIST` returns true if none of the items in the list have a "true" `ref` return -- so none are references, but all are mere strings; the "bottom" of the data structure.

That part of the code prints the data structure as

```
{
  age  => 30,
  cars => [
            { models => "Fiesta Focus Mustang", name => "Ford" },
            { models => "320 X3 X5", name => "BMW" },
            { models => "500 Panda", name => "Fiat" },
          ],
  name => "John",
}
```

Even if those arrays were much longer they'd still be printed on one line.

However, this still bears a particular format since `Data::Dump` needs to "serialize" data structures in such a way so that they can be read back in (and rebuilt) by perl.  (But, once we customized how the array is printed this string *cannot* be read back into a data structure.)

On the other hand, [Data::Printer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer) doesn't care for serialization or Perl data -- it is the tool to only *show data* for review.  It has many features, and in particular one can write filters.

So the use of it in the demo above is a take on what the question asks: print arrays on one line, and I assume only those that are at the "bottom" of a data structure, having no further references. That prints (also colorized, not seen here)

```
{
    age    30,
    cars   [
        {
            models   "Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang",
            name     "Ford"
        },
        {
            models   "320", "X3", "X5",
            name     "BMW"
        },
        {
            models   "500", "Panda",
            name     "Fiat"
        }
    ],
    name   "John"
}
```

This can be customized far more.

I strongly suggest not to fiddle with printing details of specific data formats, like JSON, using regex; it's going to be very messy and unreliable, and mostly a waste of time.  (Except in the simplest of cases, or to fine-tune a library's output...)

---

And more for the record here's a regex that rewrites that JSON as wanted

```
perl -0777 -wpE'
    s{\[ ([^[]+) \] }{ q([) . $1 =~ s/\s*\n+\s*/ /gr . q(]) }gex
' spread_out.json
```

The pattern as it stands would be badly confused by a literal `[` or `]` in a string inside of an array.

Note that this still leaves those empty lines.  If you want those cleaned out as well add another regex for that, or first parse-and-rewrite the file, with `jq` for example.

But again I don't recommend changing your data like this for a minor benefit in readability. I'd rather keep the data itself (JSON) as is (correct and safe) and parse it and then work with it using reliable dedicated tools, for instance like in the program above.

I also do not recommend relying on this regex as it hasn't been tested enough and small changes in data might break it.